# What is the difference between i++ in the if condition and i++ after the if inside a while loop?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

```
int i = 0 ;
        while(i < N)
        {
            char ptype ;
            scanf("%c" , &ptype);
            //getchar();
            if(ptype == 'P'){
                scanf("%d" , &passto);
                //printf("\n");
                preplayer = arr[top];
                top++;
                arr[top] = passto;
                printf("%d\n", i); 
                i++;               
            }
            if(ptype == 'B'){
                int tempplayer = arr[top];
                top++;
                arr[top] = preplayer ;
                preplayer = tempplayer;
                i++;
            }
            //++i;
        }
```

And i++ not in if condition but before while:

```
int i = 0 ;
    while(i < N)
    {
        char ptype ;
        scanf("%c" , &ptype);
        if(ptype == 'P'){
            scanf("%d" , &passto);
            //printf("\n");
            preplayer = arr[top];
            top++;
            arr[top] = passto;
            printf("%d\n", i); 
            //i++;               
        }
        if(ptype == 'B'){
            int tempplayer = arr[top];
            top++;
            arr[top] = preplayer ;
            preplayer = tempplayer;
            //i++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Both of them gives the different results.
Assume other variables are defined above the code like N = 10; and other integers and characters are also defined.

The above two codes give different results in the case of below input:

```
1
10 23
P 86
P 63
P 60
B
P 47
B
P 99
P 9
B
B
```

Comment: when both conditions are satisfied i is incremented twice on the first example but only once on the second example

Comment: @NotGaeL Both conditions can never be satisfied if  I read correctly, because `ptype` can only have one value, and the `if` clause doesn't change that value.

Comment: also, in the first example i will not increment if none of the conditions is satisfied but in the second it will anyway

Comment: by reassigning the content of `ptype` to `'B'` in the first loop. Isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 2):

The logical difference between the two code snippets is that in the first one, the variable `i` only gets incremented if the `ptype` is `'B'` or `'P'`.  However, in the second snippet, `i` gets incremented with each iteration of the `while` loop regardless of what the value of `ptype` is.

In the second version, the `while` loop would iterate a maximum of `N` times, regardless of the input.  However, the first version would iterate an unlimited amount of times, stopping only after either `'B'` or `'P'` has been entered `N` times.

Answer (score 1):

> First case:

inside if condition, i will get increment by one if ptype is equal to p and again it will be incremented by one if ptype is also equal to B so, total increment on i will be 2 (1+1) `if and only if both conditions are met.` so, it means no increment will happen on i if both conditions aren't met.

> Second Case:

i++ outside if but inside while: so i will get incremented by one on every iteration of while irrespective of if conditions. so, total increment on i will be 1 for each while iteration.

So, in first case i will get incremented two times if both 'if' conditions are met, while it will get incremented by one on every iteration of while loop in second case

Comment: In the case of the first case i is incremented by 2 and I don't understand the reason for it though I completely understand your answer but when you answer is considered it shouldn't give different results in the case of the above input.

Comment: I already mentioned that i will be incremented two times first for ptype == 'P' and second time for ptype == 'B' so, total increment on i will be 2 (1+1)

Comment: I have already mentioned that increment will happen two times if and only if  ptype = p and also equal to B @tod

Comment: @AmbrishPathak in first case the reason for it to increment twice is because in one line it is reading a character and then an integer so in each line while loop is executing twice.

Comment: @tod yeah the code is correct i got the answer of it to increment twice you can read above.

Comment: exactly what i was trying to convey @SamyakUpadhyay

Comment: so what's wrong in **if and only if both conditions are met** i was just trying to explain the logic in generic way, nowhere i have mentioned that both conditions will met. @tod

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that having the count increments within the if satements means that it will increment if either the two listed options occur and  having it out of the if statements means that it will always increment.
This issue at hand is that if ptype !==  "P" || 'B' then it will not increment.

Answer (score 0):

**i++ in the if condition:**

Here `i` will only be incremented if `ptype` that is, the scanned character is either **P** or **B**. In other words, `i` will be incremented when the control will enter either of the `if` block.

**i++ after the if inside a while loop**

In this case, `i` will be incremented in every iteration of the `while` loop.

Moreover, the first case also implies that the `while` loop will iterate for more than `N` number of iterations if the desired characters are not scanned. Whereas, in the second case while loop will only iterate for `N` iterations irrespective of the fact that the desired character(s) is found or not.